# What is the differences between Suitecrm and CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, civicrm-home

I am wondering to know about differences between CRMs, especially suitecrm and CiviCRM when can I use them and can I use both of them on WordPress website together?

Comment: Hi raha, maybe you can add more details about your objectives. Are you selecting software for your organization?

Comment: Thanks but I would like to have another question as a Is it possible to connect CiviCRM with LDAP or not?

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM is made for non-profits. The *C* in CiviCRM points to your constituents. These are organisations and persons that share the mission of the non-profit. You can use CiviCRM to store the contact details, like address, telephone, and email, but it also has specific modules for specific non-profits processes like:

- CiviContribute to register donations.
- CiviMembership to register members.
- CiviEvent to register participants for events.

I do not know SuiteCRM but mostly the *C* in CRM is short for customer, and the application supports the process of selling products and services

Your choice of the software depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering to know is CiviCRM like other CRMs or no just they have the same name "CRM"?

Comment: CRM means Customer Relationship Management. It's just the type of database system that it is. There are a lot of CRMs out there and they can be very different in what services are available through them. At the core, they all store customer/client info for you. Really you need to know what *YOU* need to use the database for in order to choose what one would be good for you. Why do you need the database? What will you do with it? How will the public interact with it

Comment: Thanks, dear Kainuk, I have a list of clients in LDAP and I want when a client sends a request for membership if her/his information exists in LDAP she/he gets a confirmation email. and for membership, I want to use CRM and then connect the CRM with LDAP. but I am not sure about which CRM.

Comment: Hi @raha, I have updated your question with the above information.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used SuiteCRM, so I couldn't tell you the difference. I can tell you that it's never a good idea to use more than one CRM if you can help it. Otherwise you end up with data in two different places, which makes ensuring that you have the best, up-to-date information difficult. If Jane Smith is in both databases with the same mailing address, but different phone numbers and email addresses, which is the correct one?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know about the main purpose of these CRMS. I am not sure are they same or not and even can I use both of them or not?

Comment: Can you use them both? Likely. The problem is that your data will become so fractured that you'll likely wish you hadn't used them both. The main purpose of any CRM is to track information on your customers, clients, donors, etc. CiviCRM can collect information on them, you can send emails, people can sign up for events (paid and/or free), people can make donations, people can become members, etc. Like I said, I haven't used the other one, so I don't know what add-ons are available for it. On the surface, it doesn't do many of those things I just listed.

Comment: Thank you, dear Jenni, yan your comments are really helpful for me and I have one more question about CiviCRM, can I use CiviCRM for online stores website or not? for tracking sales and marketing?

Comment: It's not a store - most CRMs are not. They may allow you to do paid sign ups for an event, but the setup is not there to sell actual items. But there are ecommerce solutions that tie into CiviCRM and update contact information there. You can do marketing - mass emails and such. Tracking sales is more of something for your ecommerce solution.